# .tab-focus() Twitter Bootstrap working on a elements, how possible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

In version 2.3.2 of Twitter Bootstrap you can find this in mixins.less:

```
// Webkit-style focus
// ------------------
.tab-focus() {
  // Default
  outline: thin dotted #333;
  // Webkit
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

You can also find that this mixin is being used in forms.less and buttons.less.

However, it's NOT being using in scaffolding.less where I find this for normal links:

```
// Links
// -------------------------

    a {
      color: @linkColor;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover,
    a:focus {
      color: @linkColorHover;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

However, I found out, that changing the values of `.tab-focus()` also affects the `:focus` for my normal a elements (links). How is that possible?? How is the CSS of `.tab-focus()` in TB v. 2.3.2 applies to my links? I can't find it!

PS: I do see that in the latest version of TB they applied it, see below, however the question it how it is possible in v. 2.3.2 where it's not applied that is does affect `:focus`.

```
// Links

a {
  color: @link-color;
  text-decoration: none;

  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: @link-hover-color;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

  &:focus {
    .tab-focus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are importing `reset.less` you will find it is in there.

From bootstrap reset.less

```
// Focus states
a:focus {
  .tab-focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason this file was not opened in my text-editor :-S.